# Link data: Angular

Tags: angularjs

My angular app needs to link together two different data objects, or something like that.  I'm having trouble putting this into words.

Data ::::

```
$scope.users = [{userid: "5", name: "Bobby"},{userid: "3", name: "Fett"}];
$scope.comments = [{id: "1", content: "a comment", userid: "3"},{id: "2", content: "another comment", userid: "3"}];
```

Directive ::::

```
<article ng-repeat="comment in comments">
   Posted by: {{user.name}} Comment: {{comment.content}}
</article>
```

Obviously, {{user.name}} isn't going to work.  But the idea is to get the user name from the matching comment userid.

Not really sure where to start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be a user index to get the corresponding user:

```
var userIndex = {};
for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
  userIndex[users[i].userid] = users[i];
}

$scope.userIndex = userIndex;
$scope.comments = comments;
```

Using this index you can get the username:

```
<article ng-repeat="comment in comments">
  Posted by: {{ userIndex[comment.userid].name}} Comment: {{comment.content}}
</article>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzcZ4DanUAENBQdYYxRL?p=preview).